# Critique my proof of $\forall x \in\mathbb{Z}, \ x \ \text{is even} \Rightarrow 3x + 7 \ \text{is odd}$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Let me know if this proof is correct and how I can improve it.

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and assume $x$ is even. Thus, $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t $2k = x$. $$\therefore 3x + 7 = 3(2k) + 7 = 6k + 7 = 2(3k + 3) + 1$$
B/c $3k + 3 \in \mathbb{Z}$, we conclude that $3x + 7$ is odd by definition and $x \text{ is even} \Rightarrow 3x + 7 \text{ is odd}$.

Comment: Why do you write $\equiv$ instead of $=$?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos I'm not sure myself. I guess I just liked it more, but I suppose that's confusing.

Comment: Looks good to me. I guess if you wanted you could then write let $3k+3 = n$ st $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ therefore $ = 2n + 1$ which is odd $\forall n$. Then just conclude the proof as you did. To be honest the step isn't totally necessary and it more just drives home the strategy of the proof.

Comment: This looks good to me. Another possible proof is to say that adding an even number doesn't change the parity. So $3x+7$ and $7$ have the same parity, i.e. odd (nb this is a door opening to modular arithmetic...).